# Effect of the nature of noise on the spectrum of a random matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Consider the following two equations

$X = M + \eta_1$

$Y = M + \eta_2$

where, $X\in\mathrm{R}^{n\times n}$, ia a real random matrix with mean $M\in\mathrm{R}^{n\times n}$. $\eta_1$ is Gaussian white noise with mean $0$ and covariance $\sigma^2I_{n\times n}$. while $Y\in\mathrm{C}^{n\times n}$, ia a complex random matrix with the same mean $M$. $\eta_2$ is complex Gaussian white noise with same mean $0$ and covariance $\sigma^2I_{n\times n}$. As such, $X$ and $Y$ have same mean but they differ in the nature of noise. Will the eigenvalues of the two matrix $X$ and $Y$ have same mean or will they differ?

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries.  If each entry is random, the covariance matrix should be $n^2 \times n^2$, not $n \times n$.  Do you mean that the matrix entries of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ are independent and Gaussian with mean $0$ and covariance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Entries of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ are independent and Gaussian(complex for $\eta_2$) with mean 0 and covariance $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the eigenvalues (counted by multiplicity) is the trace, and that is 
linear, so the means of the sums  of the eigenvalues of $X$ and $Y$ are both equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $M$.  Apart from that, I don't understand the question.  Each matrix has $n$ eigenvalues, usually distinct and complex.  There is no canonical way to single out
a particular eigenvalue of $X$ or $Y$, so how can you ask whether they have the same mean?

Comment: Here is what I am asking. Take about $100000$ samples of $X$ by adding Gaussian white noise. For each sample calculate the eigenvalues. There will be $n$ eigenvalues. Let us consider only the largest eigenvalue. Thus there will be $100000$ samples of the largest eigenvalues corresponding to samples of $X$. Find the mean of the largest eigenvalue. Call it $\mu_{\lambda_1x}$.Similarly, generate samples of $Y$ by adding complex Gaussian noise.Once again find the eigenvalues for samples of Y.Find the mean of the largest eigenvalue. Call it $\mu_{\lambda_1y}$.Is $\mu_{\lambda_1x}=\mu_{\lambda_1y}$?

Comment: I'll assume this means the largest in absolute value, since the eigenvalues are complex in general.  This still doesn't specify which one, though, since in the case of $X$ when the eigenvalues are not real they are complex conjugates of each other, and both members of a complex conjugate pair have the same absolute value.